# Regular expression with RTL Language

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this code:

```
patternString = "הבא  [a-fA-F0-9]{3,10}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strBody);
if (matcher.find())
{
    return matcher.group();
}
```

I have string strBody in Hebrew that is:

```
. משהו גדול קורה פה הבא  711063
```

I need only the number after the word "הבא" that may be 3-10 digits long.

What I get now as result is:

```
הבא  711063
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: What do you wish to get returned? There are no numbers after the word "הבא" in your example.

Comment: In Hebrew is right lo left

Answer (score 1):

Just capture the part you want to print through  capturing group.

```
String strBody = ". משהו גדול קורה פה הבא  711063";
String patternString = "הבא  ([a-fA-F0-9]{3,10})";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strBody);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

OR

You could try this regex also if you want to match only 3 to 10 digits following `הבא` string.

```
String patternString = "הבא  (\\d{3,10})";
```

Output:

```
711063
```

Comment: I just learned that hebrew is read from right to left. So your code seems to work. When does the matcher read in which direction?

Comment: Both @chris and OP: the directionality of Hebrew has nothing to do with regular expressions. It only matters when the string is displayed. So this answer is correct, because the only reason the Hebrew string appears on the right in the OP is that it is displayed that way. The characters are still in the original order.